# Touch movement in Unity, can this be done better or more efficiently?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, touch

This code works, though I am unsure if it can be done better and if I am using too many resources to make this work.

I am still learning and if there is anything I can find out to improve, I would like to do so.

- The code is for mobile, and moves the player the exact amount distance wise that the finger moves on screen.

  - I have it set up as is currently so that anywhere the finger is put on screen, it starts everything at zero, then upon moving it takes the zero'd out data, compares it to where the finger is on screen, takes the math from that comparison and minus it with the end position that is made at the end of the code (this is done because without doing so, the player resets to the center of the screen, or the position it was at before moving upon taking the finger off screen, then putting it back on the screen again) then finally subtracting that from the player's current position to move the player.

I've attempted looking around online for various other ways to do this, but having this code without the player resetting to the previous position if the finger is lifted then put on screen again or to the center of the screen.

```
Vector2 touchStartPos;
Vector2 touchMovedPos;
Vector2 touchDiffPos;
Vector2 touchEndPos;

public Rigidbody2D rb;

private void Start()
{
    touchStartPos = Vector2.zero;
    touchMovedPos = Vector2.zero;
    touchEndPos = Vector2.zero;
}
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Vector2 touch = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
        Touch touchType = Input.GetTouch(0);

        switch (touchType.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Began:
                touchStartPos = touch;
                break;
            case TouchPhase.Moved:
                touchMovedPos = touchStartPos - touch;
                touchDiffPos = touchMovedPos - touchEndPos;
                Vector2 touchMathedPos = rb.position - touchDiffPos;

                rb.MovePosition(touchMathedPos);

                touchEndPos = touchMovedPos;

                break;
            case TouchPhase.Ended:
                touchEndPos = Vector2.zero;
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think this would not be efficient? The only thing "wrong" I can find on your code is the repeated access of `Camera.main` which is quite expensive .. rather store this reference once in a field and you should be good ;)

Comment: Oh and you could use one vector field less and simply only have `StartPos` and `CurrentPos` and move by the difference .. `EndPos` is a bit redundant

Comment: Oh and please note the entire thing should rather be done in `FixedUpdate` ... don't call Physics related stuff (`MovePosition`) in `Update`!

Comment: From what I understood having to call so many Vector 2's was a bit much.  I also think I tried to store it in start, but it was storing the position either on a zero'd vector or it threw an error.  I'll try again once I get home and most certainly change it to FixedUpdate though!  Once I do I'll comment again and update how that went.  Thank you for replying, sorry it's in part that with me learning I'm unsure about how well my code works efficiency wise.

Comment: @derHugo So I did change it to FixedUpdate() and thank you for that, completely forgot that physics should go there, I did find that if you put the Camera.main call in Start(), I get an Index out of Range error and the code won't run at all, and attempting to rid of EndPos causes the resetting back to last position issue.  Thank you so much for trying to help!  My original version long before was just the startPos compared to what moved, but I had to develop this long method to prevent resetting, just thought it could possibly be done better.

Comment: This code and the reason for all the Vector2's was a result of testing a lot until it finally got to a point the player would move correctly, and not reset to the previous position or the center.  I was just unsure if there was perhaps a better way to do this in general.  @derHugo I want to upvote you if possible, I don't seem to have an option to do so, but if you let me know how I would be glad to.